# How does one calculate the Sachs-Wolfe effect?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, gravitational-redshift

I start from $$\Delta T/T_{0} = - \frac{1}{3c^2}\Phi$$ where $\Phi$ is the gravitational potential which can be written in its Fourier expression as $$\Phi_k = \frac{-3}{2}\left(\frac{H_0}{k}\right)^2 \Omega_{m0} \delta_k/a.$$ To calculate the [Sachs-Wolfe (SW) effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachs%E2%80%93Wolfe_effect), I begin by considering $a_{lm} = \int \Delta T/T_{0} Y_{lm}^*(\hat{r}) dr$. Following a derivation similar to that for the ISW effect by using spherical harmonic functions and Bessel function identities and finally, the Limber approximation, I arrive at an expression for $C_l$ in terms of the power spectrum of the potential fluctuations but I believe it is incorrect as it is not dimensionless and has the dimensions of [L]. Here's my final expression. Can someone spot what I have done incorrectly?

$C_l = \frac{1}{9c^4 r^2} P_{\Phi\Phi}(k=l/r)$ where $r$ is the comoving distance to the last scattering surface and $P_{\Phi\Phi}$ is the power spectrum of the potential fluctuations.
Thank you!